# Run Tomcat 7 in Windows from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, tomcat7

I need to run Tomcat from within a program. So, I am thinking of having a windows batch file to run the Tomcat. Can you please tell me what commands should be in the batch file to start tomcat 7?

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off
pushd  "path-to-tomcat-bin-directory"
call startup.bat
```

Example `path-to-tomacat-bin-directory` is `D:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\bin\`

Also you should already set the `JAVA_HOME` or `JRE_HOME` environment variable

To do that

Go to `MyComputer->rightclick->properties->Advanced->Environment Variables`

Add new User Variable JAVA_HOME

```
Variable name = JAVA_HOME 
Variable value = your_java_home_directory;your_java_home_directory/bin;
```